# I cant read the data correctly, I receive from serial port using c#

Tags: c#, vb.net, serial-port, microcontroller

#### Dear Guys

I'm working on a simple project which reads data from serial port. in fact, I can get the data in visual basic (VB) correctly. Now I tried to create it using c# but the problem is, I cant read data like I read in VB. how do I convert my VB code into C sharp ?

```
Dim buf As Variant
Dim data(5) As Variant
Dim data_dorost(3)  As Variant
Dim counter As Variant
Dim cs As Variant
Dim sending As Boolean
Private Sub Form_Load()
MSComm1.Settings = "9600,N,8,1"
MSComm1.RThreshold = 1
MSComm1.SThreshold = 1
MSComm1.InputLen = 1
MSComm1.PortOpen = True
End Sub

Private Sub MSComm1_OnComm()

Select Case MSComm1.CommEvent
        Case comEvReceive
            buf = MSComm1.Input
            buf = Asc()
            Debug.Print buf
            If buf = &HEB And counter = 0 Then
                counter = 1
                data(counter) = buf
                cs = buf
                Exit Sub
            End If

            If counter <> 0 Then
                    counter = counter + 1
                    data(counter) = buf
                     If counter = 2 Then


      Select Case data(2)
      Case 1:
      r1.BackColor = RGB(0, 255, 0)
      Text1.Text = "ON"

      Case 2:
      r1.BackColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
      Text1.Text = "OFF"



      Case 3:
      r2.BackColor = RGB(0, 255, 0)
      Text2.Text = "ON"

      Case 4:
      r2.BackColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
      Text2.Text = "OFF"





      Case 5:
      r3.BackColor = RGB(0, 255, 0)
      Text3.Text = "ON"

      Case 6:
      r3.BackColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
      Text3.Text = "OFF"





      Case 7:
      r4.BackColor = RGB(0, 255, 0)
      Text4.Text = "ON"

      Case 8:
      r4.BackColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
      Text4.Text = "OFF"





        Case 9:
      r5.BackColor = RGB(0, 255, 0)
      Text5.Text = "ON"

      Case 10:
      r5.BackColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
      Text5.Text = "OFF"





        Case 11:
      r6.BackColor = RGB(0, 255, 0)
      Text6.Text = "ON"

      Case 12:
      r6.BackColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
      Text6.Text = "OFF"




        Case 13:
      r7.BackColor = RGB(0, 255, 0)
      Text7.Text = "ON"

      Case 14:
      r7.BackColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
      Text7.Text = "OFF"




        Case 15:
      r8.BackColor = RGB(0, 255, 0)
      Text8.Text = "ON"

      Case 16:
      r8.BackColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
      Text8.Text = "OFF"





      Case 17:
      r9.BackColor = RGB(0, 255, 0)
      Text9.Text = "ON"

      Case 18:
      r9.BackColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
      Text9.Text = "OFF"



      Case 19:
      r10.BackColor = RGB(0, 255, 0)
      Text10.Text = "ON"

      Case 20:
      r10.BackColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
      Text10.Text = "OFF"





      Case 21:
      r11.BackColor = RGB(0, 255, 0)
      Text11.Text = "ON"

      Case 22:
      r11.BackColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
      Text11.Text = "OFF"





      Case 23:
      r12.BackColor = RGB(0, 255, 0)
      Text12.Text = "ON"

      Case 24:
      r12.BackColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
      Text12.Text = "OFF"





        Case 25:
      r13.BackColor = RGB(0, 255, 0)
      Text13.Text = "ON"

      Case 26:
      r13.BackColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
      Text13.Text = "OFF"







     Case 27:
      r14.BackColor = RGB(0, 255, 0)
      Text14.Text = "ON"

      Case 28:
      r14.BackColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
      Text14.Text = "OFF"





        Case 29:
      r15.BackColor = RGB(0, 255, 0)
      Text15.Text = "ON"

      Case 30:
      r15.BackColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
      Text15.Text = "OFF"

Bobi, [07.08.17 11:47]
Case 31:
      r16.BackColor = RGB(0, 255, 0)
      Text16.Text = "ON"

      Case 32:
      r16.BackColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
      Text16.Text = "OFF"
      End Select



                    counter = 0

                  If sending = True Then
                        sending = False
                        F_BYTE = &HAA
                        cs = F_BYTE
                        MSComm1.Output = Chr$(F_BYTE)
                        MSComm1.Output = Chr$(setpoint_change.Text)
                        cs = F_BYTE + setpoint_change.Text
                        cs = cs And 255
                        MSComm1.Output = Chr$(cs)
                 End If

                     End If
                    cs = cs + buf
            End If
End Select

End Sub

Private Sub setpoint_change_KeyPress(KeyAscii As Integer)
If KeyAscii = 13 Then sending = True
End Sub
```

here is a part of my c# code:

```
void _serialPort_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    int dataLength = _serialPort.BytesToRead;
    byte[] data = new byte[dataLength];
    int nbrDataRead = _serialPort.Read(data, 0, dataLength);
    if (nbrDataRead == 0)
        return;

    // Send data to whom ever interested
    if (NewSerialDataRecieved != null)
        NewSerialDataRecieved(this, new SerialDataEventArgs(data));
}
```

and here I display data, in textbox:

```
        int maxTextLength = 1000; // maximum text length in text box
        if (tbData.TextLength > maxTextLength)
            tbData.Text = tbData.Text.Remove(0, tbData.TextLength - maxTextLength);

        // This application is connected to a GPS sending ASCCI characters, so data is converted to text
    string str = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(e.Data);

    //end new
    //tbData.AppendText(e.Data[0].ToString());
    String strTemp0 = e.Data[0].ToString();


    tbData.AppendText(strTemp0);
```

#### In fact I have to receive the number of port and the value of it which I understand which one is 'OFF' and which is 'ON'.

what is the right equivalent C# code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't provided source code of COM initialization in C#, but if it is correct, than the problem can be in your receive function. You suppose that you always receive full data string, but it is not so.

If your data is more than one character, than your callback will receive the data by parts.

Comment: initialization is correct but can you tell me how can I read it?

Comment: ok, data is not received at all or do you receive some weird results?

Comment: I recieved a series of number when I print data[0]. for example when I turn ON the first port of micro my textbox shows 2503

Comment: And what did you received with VB? What did you expected to receive?

Comment: do you have e.Data encoded at ASCII? have you tried this?: string str = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(e.Data)

Comment: @ Melnikov Sergei If u check out my data which is compared by switch case command  in VB, you will find I'm waiting for the number of ports.

Comment: @mehdiamirsardari I checked your data which is compared by switch, but I don't still don't understand how often your ports' info must be received. For example: you can receive the list of all available ports every seconds. Or you can do a request for a specific port. It differs. Have you checked the contain of `data` in debug mode?

Comment: @ Melnikov Sergei In fact I receive the strange data like question mark. can u help me plz